# Type of SmartCard to signing a certificate in Java

Tags: certificate, smartcard, smartcard-reader, smartcardio

I would like to introduce additional security in my communication using smart cards. I would like smart cards to sign a server and client certificate. Each machine has its own smart card reader. Which card standard should it be? I purchased SLE5528 SLE4428 ISO 7816 but it was probably not a good choice?

Answer (score 0):

No, memory cards like SLE5528 are not a good choice, since they only store data. You need a card containing asymmetric keys and able to apply these for creating signatures. (The other parts of a certificate are easier handled by the application).

Good news is, that ISO 7816 is relevant independent of your card (but not sufficient, you need at least  users manual) and depending on whether you intended to use a javacard or a native card 7816-4, -8 and -9 may become relevant.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you then suggest what type of card should I use for the purpose described above? I already know that it must be microprocessor smart card, not memory smart card but could you give some standard or something in this style? It would be nice if it was a low-budget card because I will need a lot of such cards.

Comment: *Low budget* is typically different from the high security level achieved by a smart card solution, but with increasing numbers the price decreases as everywhere else. *PKI* and *enterprise solution smartcard* are some useful search terms. (My sales colleagues would be happy to contact you and could refer to a distributor.)

Comment: I understand, could you give me the signs of these cards? And the cheaper and the more expensive ones? It's worth adding that I'll be programming everything in Java. I will also ask for contact with the people you mentioned.

Comment: guidot hmm ? Can you help?

Comment: @dionnauyen: I tried to add a twiiter link to my account. But all keywords I can give you with the currently provided hints are already in my last comment

Comment: guidot: Okay, I have only one question...Will I be able to use JavaCards like J2A080 or J2A040 for my needs?

Comment: @dionnauyen: Yes, both card types should be fine.